# .Net Core 3.1 SPA React Application doesn't serve Hangfire dashboard / Swagger on production

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, single-page-application, hangfire

After installing the React app template from **.NET Core 3.1** using `dotnet new react` the application works perfectly in Development and Production. The problem appears when trying to use Swagger or Hangfire dashboard endpoints.

After the app is created I add the package reference for Hangfire and for practical purposes the memory storage:

```
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire" Version="1.7.*" />
<PackageReference Include="Hangfire.MemoryStorage" Version="1.7.0" />
```

In `Startup.cs`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    services.AddHangfire(config =>
        config.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
        .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
        .UseDefaultTypeSerializer()
        .UseMemoryStorage());

    services.AddHangfireServer();

    // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
    {
        configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHangfireDashboard();
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    app.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
        }
    });
}
```

After publishing the application and run it, the app works fine except the Hangfire dashboard, and trying to access the route: `/Hangfire` causes the server return the SPA index.html

[image]
[image]

But if I refresh the page doing a hard reload, the dashboard loads fine.

Same thing occurs with Swagger.

Can someone give me a hand ?

Comment: I looked at the status code "200 OK (from ServiceWorker)". I think you are working with a PWA and the service worker has cached these routes at some point. I think you should ignore the Swagger and Hangfire routes in your service worker to avoid this kind of problem. I personally don't like using the features of ASP.NET SPA. I prefer to serve my APIs and SPA from different hosts. The SPA is served much faster from a static server and your ASP.NET application would be kept clean.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will take a look at what you suggested of ignoring certain routes, but it's strange that API routes work well and not the other ones. I will look at other options if I can not make this work, but I really want to try the SPA middleware.

Comment: You're welcome. I remembered this announcement that may be relevant to you: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12890

Answer (score 0):

After following [Guilherme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1851755/guilherme-meinlschmiedt-abdo) suggestion, unregistering the service worker solved the issue. Instead of ignoring the routes, I opted to unregister it.

Thank you very much !